# How to add javascript functions in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing my first rails app i have a controller named article that have about 5 action each action with a view page how do i add a JavaScript function for a certain action in the article.coffee file

Comment: Well coffee script is not Javascript from what I understand.  You can however use vanilla JS with rails by sourcing your JS in wherever you want to include your JS.

Answer (score 0):

First thing

- Rename your file as `action.js.coffee`.

Then

- Just bind the actions on the elements for your views of action controller.

Comment: could you please show me an example ?
i have a controller named article and have an action named new how to add a javascript function on the new view page

Answer (score 0):

Well, as detailed on the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) if you didn't start your projet with the --skip-sprocket option

```
rails new myapp --skip-sprocket
```

the asset pipeline should be enable, wich means you should have files looking like this :

**Gemfile**

```
...
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
...
```

**application.html.erb**

```
...
  <title>myapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
...
```

If this samples look like your app then just add you JS in the application.js file like this :

```
...
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

function greatTutorial() {
    alert('Rails Guides are the best');
}
```

and then you'll be able to call this function in your views like this :

```
<h1 onclick="greatTutorial()">Hello World</h1>
```

If you want to write in Vanilla JS (meaning basic JavaScript, no Coffee or any preprocessor) make your js files end with ".js", but if you wish to write in CoffeeScript make them end with ".js.coffee" in order to be preprocessed before rendering. I recommend you to read the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) about the Asset Pipeline wich is a gold mine to understand how Rails deals with the assets. Hope this will help you getting started.